# How can I turn off history handling in angularjs?

Tags: url, jquery-mobile, angularjs, location, history

Is there a way to disable history and url handling of angularjs to use for example the jquery mobile history handler?

e.g. in jquery mobile you can disable the history handler by setting:

```
$.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
$.mobile.linkBindingEnabled = false;
$.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;
$.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;
```

what would the angularjs equivalent be?

Answer (score 3):

After routing configuration you have to declare delegate that will disable history tracking:

```
var app = angular.module('TagGadget', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider

        // route for the home page
        .when('/home1', {
            template: '<div ><h1>Home Page</h1><p>{{ message }}</p></div>',
            controller: 'maincontroller'
        })
        .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/home1'
      });
   });
app.config( ['$provide', function ($provide){
    $provide.decorator('$sniffer', ['$delegate', function ($delegate) {
        $delegate.history = false;
        return $delegate;
    }]);
}])
```

Comment: I'm glad I found this answer. Took me a while to figure out that AngularJS is interfering with history API. Definitely not my favorite framework by far.